# How to have an input of type MongoDB for Logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I know we can input files, and output to a mongo database. But I have a collection in my mongodb that I would like to have as an input so that I can use it with ES. Is this possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, the short answer is No, it is not possible to have an input from a database in Logstash.

EDIT

@elssar thank you for your answer:

> Actually, there is a 3rd party mongodb input for logstash -
>   github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb – elssar

Comment: Actually, there is a 3rd party mongodb input for logstash - https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb

Answer (score 9):

I have had a similar problem, the **logstash-input-mongodb** plugin is fine, but it is very limited, it also seems that it is no longer being maintained, so, I have opted for the **logstash-integration-jdbc** plugin.

I have followed the following steps to sync a MongoDB collection with ES:

First, **I have downloaded the JDBC driver** for MongoDB developed by DBSchema that you can find [here](https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/MongoDb.html).

I have prepared a **custom Dockerfile** to integrate the driver and plugins as you can see below:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.2

RUN mkdir /usr/share/logstash/drivers
COPY ./drivers/* /usr/share/logstash/drivers/

RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-integration-jdbc
RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-output-elasticsearch
```

I have configured a query that will be executed every 30 seconds and will look for documents with an insert timestamp later than the timestamp of the last query (provided with the parameter **:sql_last_value**)

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/drivers/mongojdbc2.3.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://devroot:devroot@mongo:27017/files?authSource=admin"
    jdbc_user => "devroot"
    jdbc_password => "devroot"
    schedule => "*/30 * * * * *"
    statement => "db.processed_files.find({ 'document.processed_at' : {'$gte': :sql_last_value}},{'_id': false});"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    action => "create"
    index => "processed_files"
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "password"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    cacert => "/etc/logstash/keys/certificate.pem"
  }
}
```

Hope it can help someone, regards

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the statement, as you already did, must explicitly exclude Mongo's `_id` field with `{'_id': false}`, otherwise Logstash fails converting the `org.bson.types.ObjectId` type as pointed out in [this open issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11314).

Comment: Also, appending the option `expand=true` to the connection URI (as pointed out in the [driver's documentation](https://github.com/wise-coders/mongodb-jdbc-driver#driver-features)) will expand the driver's return objects and give more natural documents to work with, without the extra nesting inside the `document` key.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a [river](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/) to pull data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch.

See the instructions here - http://www.codetweet.com/ubuntu-2/configuring-elasticsearch-mongodb/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But I was wondering if I could use Logstash with that, since it provides for an example a geoip filter which I can use for the Kibana Bettermap, as well as providing ready raw fields for me to use.

Answer (score 2):

I tried out with [Sergio Sánchez Sánche's solution suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522783/3778446) and found following updates and improvements:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/drivers/mongojdbc3.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://devroot:devroot@mongo:27017/files?authSource=admin"
    jdbc_user => "devroot"
    jdbc_password => "devroot"
    schedule => "*/30 * * * * *"
    statement => "db.processed_files.find({ 'document.processed_at' : {'$gte': new ISODate(:sql_last_value)}},{'_id': false});"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    action => "update"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{[document][uuid]}"
    index => "processed_files"
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "password"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    cacert => "/etc/logstash/keys/certificate.pem"
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- The date comparison in Mongodb has to use new ISODate to convert
  :sql_last_value
- I'd like to use "update" instead of "create" to cover
  the case of update. The query result from the section input is
  contained in "document". Assume you have a field with unique value
  "uuid", you have to use it to identify the document, because Mongodb's
  "_id" is not supported anyway.
- If you have any embedded document which has also "_id" filed, you have to exclude it, too, e.g.

  statement => "db.profiles.find({'updatedAt' : {'$gte': new    ISODate(:sql_last_value)}},
  {'_id': false, 'embedded_doc._id': false}});"

Answer (score 0):

Note as of version 4.8.2 of the Mongo JDBC plugin the jdbc_driver_class has changed, so the correct config for `input` is:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/drivers/mongojdbc4.8.2.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::com.wisecoders.dbschema.mongodb.JdbcDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://devroot:devroot@mongo:27017/files?authSource=admin"
    jdbc_user => "devroot"
    jdbc_password => "devroot"
    schedule => "*/30 * * * * *"
    statement => "db.processed_files.find({ 'document.processed_at' : {'$gte': new ISODate(:sql_last_value)}},{'_id': false});"
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a comment on another answer, not an answer itself